# Badge not loading properly in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

My index.html is not showing the badge properly on any browser. It is not showing the numbers in a colored circle. It is just showing it as if it didn't load the CSS correctly.

I tried local and CDN paths from bootstrap and jquery but the problem is not resolved.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-danger" >
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-level="close">&times;</a>
  File is deleted!
</div> 

<a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">5</span> </a>
```

I want it to show the text "Messages" and then a colored circle with the text "5".

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/ you simply need to read the doc .. missing the color and the pill class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This solutions

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>




<body>
    <html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-level="close">&times;</a>File is deleted!
        </div>

        <a href="#">Messages <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">5</span> </a>


    </body>

    </html>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What did you change, and why is that a solution? Always provide text with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The color class is missing, like for example

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">5</span>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="alert alert-danger" >
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-level="close">&times;</a> File is deleted!
</div> 
<a href="#">Messages <span class="badge badge-primary rounded-circle">5</span></a>
```

Additionally, for the circle effect, use [`.rounded-circle`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) bootstrap class, which sets `border-radius: 50%;` css property.

Comment: it worked.. how to get it in circle shape? it is box

Comment: `border-radius` add class: `class="rounded-circle"`:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/

Comment: @JosephFellow add to your css `.badge {border-radius: 1rem;}`

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy better use bootstrap classes as `rounded-circle`

Comment: @לבנימלכה sure yes :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using bootstrap 4

just change the span class to (badge badge-secondary)

```
<a href="#">Messages <span class="badge badge-secondary">5</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentaion of bootstrap:
[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/)

Badge colors change:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge badge-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge badge-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">Info</span>
<span class="badge badge-light">Light</span>
<span class="badge badge-dark">Dark</span>
```

To make badge round add class badge-pill

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Info</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">Light</span>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">Dark</span>
```